# What to Do if Drag&Drop Doesn't Work in Manjaro/XFCE/LightDM

Tags: linux, drag-and-drop, manjaro

I'm aware that in Linux several different components are required to make some graphic appear on the screen and have mouse actions cause some intended behaviour. However, I'm not familiar enough with which part does what and where to look at in case something doesn't work. Therefore, I can't name the problem like a pro would do... So bear with me, I'm trying :)

Anyway, here's what I think is relevant from my system (please ask if something important is missing):

```
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ uname -a
Linux runlikehell 4.4.55-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 19 07:00:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ inxi -SG
System:    Host: runlikehell Kernel: 4.4.55-1-MANJARO x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Manjaro Linux
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK208 [GeForce GT 710B]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 driver: nvidia
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2
           GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ lightdm -v
lightdm 1.20.0
[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$ mhwd-gpu
Using default
Default lib32 support: true
:: status
  lib32-libGl: '/usr/lib32/nvidia/libGL.so'
  lib32-libGLESv1: '/usr/lib32/nvidia/libGLESv1_CM.so'
  lib32-libGLESv2: '/usr/lib32/nvidia/libGLESv2.so'
  lib32-libEGL: '/usr/lib32/nvidia/libEGL.so'
  libGl: '/usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so'
  libGLESv1: '/usr/lib/nvidia/libGLESv1_CM.so'
  libGLESv2: '/usr/lib/nvidia/libGLESv2.so'
  libEGL: '/usr/lib/nvidia/libEGL.so'
  xorg configuration file: '/etc/X11/mhwd.d/nvidia.conf'

[stefan@runlikehell ~]$ cat /etc/X11/mhwd.d/nvidia.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.26  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Thu Dec  8 19:07:46 PST 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "1"
    Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard     "yes"
    Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection


[sjngm@runlikehell ~]$
```

Coming from Windows I'm used to drag something out of one application into another, specifically drag an image from a browser into the file manager and cause that to store the image in the folder where I dropped it. On my Unix-system I'm trying to drag from Vivaldi and drop into Thunar.

***And now my question***: What do I need to do (configure, install, ...) to make that work on my system? Is one application not capable of doing this? Do I need another file manager?

I mean in Thunar I can drag&drop files and folders, but that's only possible within Thunar. So it's not completely "not working".